# How to change a vector name in a function?

Tags: r, function, vector

I want to do graphical outputs such as boxplots or graphs using a function. So that I can plot several dataframes, changing only the column name each time.

For example :

```
boxplot_func = function(column){
  boxplot(dataframe1$column, dataframe2$column)}

boxplot_func(mean)
boxplot_func(max)
etc.
```

But R doesn't seem to compute `mean` or `max` in the function. Do you know a way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to pass the column as a character string and use `[[` to access the column in your function:

A simple example using `mtcars`:

```r
boxplot_func = function(column) {
  boxplot(mtcars[[column]], mtcars[[column]])
}

boxplot_func("mpg")
```

[image]